# I am stuck in a tent in Skyrim. How can I get out?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My character got stuck in a tent in one dungeon. I was doing some quest in some dungeon, I saw a monster in a tent, I went to kill the monster, I killed it but in the process I accidentally went in the tent. When I tried to get out of the tent, I discovered that my hero cant move past its entrance. I tried to Whirlwind out of the tent, but without any success. There was a bed in the tent, so I went to sleep (hoping that it will fix the glitch) but things get worse - my save was overridden and my 3 last saves now are in the tent (stuck). I'm not outdoors, and I cannot fast travel from there. I can't only load my hero from a previous save (which is 5 levels lower).

Is there a cheat for going through walls, or any other kind of getting out of the tent?

Comment: Apparently, you are not alone.  http://www.ask.com/answers/104823481/skyrim-irkngthand-grand-cavern-falmer-tent-glitch-how-to-escape-the-tent  http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/136246-falmer-tents-getting-stuck.html  http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111115151854AAzQRHZ

Comment: @EBongo The Falmer are masters at trapping their enemies.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Open the console using the tilde key (~) and type TCL (which toggles collision, letting you go through walls or other solid objects). Once you're in a safe zone repeat the process to turn it off.

Answer (score 4):

I made it on Nintendo Switch!
Conjure a familiar in front of the exit.
Punch him until it starts attacking you.
Keep jumping on him pointing towards the exit of the Falmer tent!